# How to tell what checkboxes are checked on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pageload, checked

I already have a `change` event/listener going on, but this doesn't do anything when someone refreshes the page...etc (page load) and there are already checked checkboxes.

How can I check to see if ANY checkboxes are checked on page load, and get their name/value (whatever)?

Example:  I check to see if ANY checkboxes in a specific DOM element are checked like so:

```
if($("#allocation input:checkbox").is(':checked')){
    console.log("something is checked");
}
```

But how can I actually get the `id`'s of the ones that are checked upon page load?

Something like a `$this.id` inside of the above? (but that doesn't work of course).

Or can you tie an `event.target` into the above `is.('checked')` conditional somehow?

Again, I already have something in place for the `.change()` (user interaction) portion, but if a checkbox is checked and someone reloads the page, the checkbox is still checked (and I need to cater to that still).

My final solution here:  (similar/same as suggested below)

KEY.. use the 'each' function..

```
//on page load
                    $('#allocation input:checked').each(function() {
                        if($(this).is(':checked')){
                            //console.log("CB CHECK: " + $(this).attr('id'));
                            var targetID = $(this).attr('id');
                            $('#' + targetID + 'amount').prop('disabled', false);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: You don't need to check `$(this).is(':checked')`, because all the elements in that array are checked for sure, so your check will always be true and thus it is redundant. Also, unless the value of the `id` has changed (which is very unlikely), there is no need to get the value directly from the attribute `$(this).attr('id')`. Simply get it directly from the property `this.id`. Easier to read/write and more efficient.

Comment: ahh.. correct!   Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the selectors `"#allocation input:checked"` (or `"#allocation input:checkbox:checked"`) which will give you an array of all checkboxes that are checked. Then loop through them with `each()` and you can get the `id` with `this.id`.

Put the entire code in a self-executing function `(function() {...})();` at the bottom of your code or at least bellow all the checkboxes. Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  $("#allocation input:checked").each(function() {
    console.log(this.id + " is checked")
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="allocation">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" checked="checked" /> Option 1
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" /> Option 2
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" /> Option 3
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk4" checked="checked" /> Option 4
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk5" checked="checked" /> Option 5
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

this will loop through ALL checked checkboxes and console.log their ID.

ID is accessible through PROP.

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).prop("id"));
});
```

EDIT: Grabs their name and value also

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).prop("id"),$(this).prop("name"),$(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Don't convert `this` to jQuery just to get the `id` property, simply use `this.id` instead. Same with the other properties.

Comment: thanks...  that more or less what I stumbled on too.

-
Posted above in OP